# How to programatically set options for a selected word?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, style

I want to create a palette with buttons and have it apply to the selected word. No matter what combination I try it always applies it to the entire cell.

Imagine that in the sentence:

```
 "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
```

The word "**brown**" is selected. I want the font to change only for that word.

The code I have tried is below and in all cases it changes the font for the entire cell.

```
CreatePalette[
  Row[{
    Spacer[30],
    Column[
     {
      Button["Courier Selection",
       SetOptions[NotebookSelection[InputNotebook[]], 
        FontFamily -> "Courier New"]
       ],
      Button["Courier Next Word",
       SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], Next, Word];
       SetOptions[NotebookSelection[InputNotebook[]], 
        FontFamily -> "Courier New"]
       ],
      Button["Courier First Word",
       SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], Before, CellContents];
       SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], Next, Word];
       SetOptions[NotebookSelection[InputNotebook[]], 
        FontFamily -> "Courier New"]
       ],
      Button["Courier Entire Cell",
       SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], Before, CellContents];
       SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], All, Word];
       SetOptions[NotebookSelection[InputNotebook[]], 
        FontFamily -> "Courier New"]
       ]
      }
     ]
    }],
  WindowTitle -> "Set Font for Selected Word",
  WindowSize -> {170, 120}
  ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [Front End Tokens](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/FrontEndTokens.html).  Here is a button that turns the selected text red:

```
Button["Color", FrontEndTokenExecute["FontColor", Red]]
```

In a Notebook:

[image]

Comment: Example works great. Extended to include FontFamily, ...

I was unable to understand the capability from the documentation. Example makes it crystal clear.

Comment: @Jack The documentation is not complete in this area so trial and error is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

For a variety of reasons I still use V9 most of the time and when I ran your code on my Mac (OS 10.10) I found the same problem. Mr Wizard has provided an alternative way for you to achieve what you want but the question remains why your code didn't work. I made some changes to your code that should make it work:

```
CreatePalette[
  Column[{Button["Courier Selection", 
     SetOptions[NotebookSelection[InputNotebook[]], 
      FontFamily -> "Courier New"]],

Button["Courier Next Word", 
 SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], Next, Word]; 
 SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], All, Word];
 SetOptions[NotebookSelection[InputNotebook[]], 
  FontFamily -> "Courier New"]],

Button["Courier First Word", 
 SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], Before, CellContents];
 SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], All, Word];
 SetOptions[NotebookSelection[InputNotebook[]], 
  FontFamily -> "Courier New"]],

Button["Courier Entire Cell", 
 SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], All, CellContents];
 SetOptions[NotebookSelection[InputNotebook[]], 
  FontFamily -> "Courier New"]]}], 
  WindowTitle -> "Set Font for Selected Word", 
  WindowSize -> {170, 120}];
```

...But I ran into similar problems to you. So I decided to try some of the `NotebookSelection` examples in the docs

[image]

and what I got was with V8:

[image]

...with V9:

[image]

...and with V10:

[image]

So it seems they somehow managed to break `NotebookSelection` in V9 -- in the OS X version at least --but have fixed it in V10. You didn't mention which version you are using but I presume V9??

So there were a few minor problems with the code but more importantly a bug in V9. Using the code above this will work for you in V8 or V10.

Comment: Makes me feel better. I saw the same example as you in the documentation but was sure that I was doing something wrong (usually the case).

At the moment I am using Mathematica 9.0

Comment: behaviour is the same on Windows, at least for me: V8 and V10 do the right thing, V9 changes both words to bold...